# Поместить static/const в интерфейс или абстрактный класс C#

Tags: c#, const, интерфейс

Как можно определить интерфейс или абстрактный класс, который вынудит реализовывать публичную константу (отображаемое пользователям наименование класса, нужно вывести список до того как юзверь тыкнет в заинтересовавший его класс) и статический метод (например GetInstance)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никак.

Это не поддерживается языком.

Вы *можете* сэмулировать константу уровня экземпляра класса через свойство с одним лишь геттером:

```
interface ISomething
{
    string ClassName { get; }
}
```

Статические методы в интерфейс не вписываются никак, вообще. В текущей концепции вы получаете доступ к статическому объекту по имени класса, а не по экземпляру объекта. А поддержка интерфейсов реализована обычным образом, через таблицы виртуальных методов.

Тем не менее, в будущих версиях языка возможны изменения, разрешающие схожую функциональность (generic-условия на наличие статического метода). Design team языка C# [обсуждает](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/420) эту возможность.

---

Вот пример того, как *динамически* проверить наличие статического метода:

```
interface ISomething
{
}

static class SomethingChecker
{
    public static Func<T> CheckAndGetBuider<T>() where T : ISomething
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var builder = type.GetMethod("GetInstance",
                                     BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        // а есть ли такой метод?
        if (builder == null)
            throw new Exception();
        // а не требует ли метод generic-аргумент?
        if (builder.IsGenericMethod)
            throw new Exception();
        // а не требует ли метод параметров?
        if (builder.GetParameters().Length != 0)
            throw new Exception();
        // а подходящий ли тип результата?
        if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(builder.ReturnType))
            throw new Exception();
        // все проверки пройдены
        return () => (T)builder.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Здесь рабочий пример использованием: http://ideone.com/bPyoEf

Comment: Может есть какой-то обходной путь?

Comment: Ссылка на обсуждение статических свойств есть?

Comment: Обходные пути есть. Можно, например, определить метод в интерфейсе. Или потребовать у пользователя ещё и factory. Вы не сможете возложить контроль за соблюдением правильности полностью на компилятор, просто пропишите в документации, что необходимы такие-то свойства, иначе правильная работа не гарантирована. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Athari: Сейчас поищу...

Comment: Документацию никто не читает, а если кто-то и читает, то всё равно забудет, а рано или поздно даже тот кто её писал забудет - это грустный человеческий фактор

Comment: @Athari: Не нашёл на гитхабе (не умею искать?), вот например старое обсуждение на codeplex: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/541436 (но тут нет людей из dev team). Ищу ещё.

Comment: @QuAzI: А вот это вы можете проверять в рантайме и бросать исключение, если что :-)

Comment: VladD, поделись пожалуйста экземплом?

Comment: @VladD Таких обсуждений на CodePlex немало. Обычно на них из команды даже не отвечают. Вот если первый пост от команды — уже есть ненулевой шанс, что что-то доживёт до релиза. И то большой вопрос. Вроде, для C# 7 ничего подобного не перечислялось даже в жанре "было бы неплохо".

Comment: @Athari: А как насчёт этого: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9415463/276994 ?

Comment: @QuAzI: Сейчас состряпаю.

Comment: @VladD Если я правильно понял "interface type definition can define and implement static methods", то речь не про то, как заставить реализующих интерфейс реализовать статический метод, а как положить реализованный статический метод прямо в интерфейс.

Comment: @QuAzI: Готово, обновил ответ

Comment: @Athari: И правда. Ищу дальше.

Comment: @Athari: [Нашёл](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/420)! Пункт 2: Generic constraints about static methods or constructors. Это именно то, что нужно ОПу. Это _не_ статические методы в интерфейсе, но решает ту же задачу.

Comment: @QuAzI: дополнил код несколькими проверками

Comment: @VladD Любопытно. Интересно, кто успеет раньше: шарп трейты или плюсы концепты. :)

Comment: @Athari: Учитывая, что версия стандарта плюсов выходит каждые 3 года, поставлю на шарп. Хотя конечно не факт, да.

Comment: @VladD C# 6 ещё не вышел, в C# 7, похоже, уже не войдёт (в последних [Design Notes по C#7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1921) ничего подобного нет)... То есть минимум C# 8. С другой стороны, в C++ концепты мучали, урезали, а потом взяли и выкинули.

Comment: @Athari: Угу. У C# вроде цикл должен быть короче, особенно с выходом Roslyn. Ждём-с.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23052/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd--static-const----).

Answer (score 2):

На уровне языка это реализовать невозможно.

Если вы хотите задать некое свойство для всего класса, то можно вместо статического свойства типа `string` завести статическое свойство типа `IDictionary<Type, string>`. Пусть каждый класс в статическом конструкторе записывает в словарь своё название.

Если вы используете dependency injection, то подобное свойство можно добавить как мета-информацию к классу, например, с помощью атрибутов.

Если при работе с этим классом всегда есть экземпляр, то можно добавить нестатическое свойство. В этом случае свойство не будет статическим, но смысл останется прежним.

В целом, возможных реализаций много, и что вы выберете — зависит от вашей конкретной ситуации: как вы используете значение, когда и как создаются экземпляры и т.п.

Comment: Статический конструктор будет вызываться каждый раз при обращении к любому члену класса - дорого и чревато TypeInitializaionException в случае чего.

Как относительно дёшево выводить метаинформацию класса в UI и, главное, как заставить программистов заполнять ВСЮ метаинформацию, как обязывает например интерфейс?

Экземляра нет, т.к. инициализировать кучу классов только чтобы показать пользователю инфо о них, а потом из них использовать только 1-2 класса - дорого

Comment: @QuAzI Вообще-то статический конструктор вызывается один раз на класс.

Comment: @QuAzI DI есть? Ну пусть DI подцепляет классы с мета-информацией, и если что-то отсутствует, то падает сразу на запуске. Синтаксически заставить нацепить атрибут нельзя. Падение сразу при запуске — вполне нормальный вариант, по-моему.

Comment: Падать при запуске моветон, ИМХО. Очень легко в таком варианте нашкодить и начнёт рандомно падать у конечного юзверя. Если проект собрался и юниттесты прошли - оно не должно падать. DI пока что нет

Comment: @QuAzI Добавьте тест на загрузку мета-информации о классах. Он будет падать при тех же условиях, что и приложение.